# Access private definitions in base clause of friend class template

Tags: c++, templates

Is it legal in C++ to make a base class specification of a class template `B` dependent on private definitions of a class `A` which is friends with the class template `B`? Example code:

```cpp
struct Empty {};

template <typename T>
struct B;

struct A
{
    friend struct B<A>;

private:
    using Base = Empty;
};

template <typename T>
struct B : T::Base
{
};

int main()
{
    B<A> test;
    return 0;
}
```

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/g/HFKaTQ

The code compiles fine with Clang trunk (and older versions) and MSVC 19 (VS 2017) but fails to compile with GCC trunk (and older version):

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of 'class B<A>':
test.cpp:21:7:   required from here
test.cpp:15:8: error: 'using Base = class Empty' is private within this context
 struct B : T::Base
        ^
test.cpp:11:20: note: declared private here
  using Base = Empty;
                    ^
```

Which compiler is wrong?

EDIT: By the way, the code compiles in GCC if `B` is converted into a regular class (removing the template parameter). So, I guess it is also supposed to work in the class template case. Also cppreference says: "The friend itself can also inherit from private and protected members of this class. (since C++11)"

Comment: File a [rejects-valid] bug report against GCC. Most likely they'll admit it's a bug, but maybe they'll tell you why they think it's ill-formed.

Comment: @Brian Yes, thank you. I already did this in the last weeks but forgot to update the question/provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly this is a bug in GCC. Submitted as [Bug 82613](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82613).